# How to start Ubuntu 14.04 after deleting gnome desktop environment

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gnome

I had gnome desktop installed over Unity and now after removing it I cannot start ubuntu, it gets me into tty1.
[image]

After Ctrl + Alt + 7 
[image]

**Update**

startx works but after rebooting it will go into tty1 again

[image]

**Update 2**
sudo apt-get update
[image]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You might have better luck at a Ubuntu support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to edit your /etc/default/grub file and you should have this line in it `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`. Basically you should have `quiet splash` as value for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` key.

Then run: `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.

Comment: Grub cmdline had quiet splash as valur.

Comment: I am able to select ubuntu from grub, then after loading screen it gets me to tty1

Comment: Hoping you are running lightdm as DM, Try running these commands: 

1. `sudo stop lightdm`
2. `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`
3. `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
4. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: Its seems like Im not connecting to the internet so i cant update

Comment: Try running this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and reboot.

Comment: Lightdm is not installed ((

Comment: Ah! Can you try to connect to internet? or download the package on other machine and install it on this machine? and what is returned when you run `who -r` ?

Comment: After who -r gives me, run-level 2 2016-05-04 13:26

Comment: Try this `sudo init 5` and see.

Comment: If I run again who -r it has a last=5

Comment: Can you try to install the lightdm now? I mean, check whether you are connected to the internet or not. ping google.com or try installing the package.

Comment: Are you able to connect to internet after changing the runlevel?

Comment: I connected to the internet, and made my updates/upgrades it installed lightdm, installed unity-desktop, but now I cannt see the sidebar, cant get into terminal from desktop. But thats another qurstion

Comment: I will mark your answer as thr answer, for helping me

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, login into your account.

After that, you can start the desktop enviroment by using the shell command `startx`.

Comment: It works, but if I restart my pc, it will go into tty1 again.

Comment: Try selecting GNOME as the default desktop enviroment in the login screen (once you had started the desktop enviroment itself).

Comment: I cant, the window where I should loggin an choose what the envitonment is missing

Comment: It seems like GNOME isn't properly installed. Have you tried updating the system and doing sudo apt-get check?

Comment: Its givving me this error Unable to fetch somr archives, maybe run apt-gey update or try with --fix-missing, but aftrr trying its still failing updating

Comment: Try sudo apt-get purge gnome and then reinstalling it.

Comment: It give me "Gnome is not installed so not removed"